# Printing multiple sheets in excel using VBA is selecting print area of only sheet for all the other sheets

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I am trying to print multiple sheets in excel but it is applying print area of the first sheet of multiple sheets to all the other sheets. I need to print the print area of individual sheets. I tried using multiple ways to select sheets, but the result is same. It's not selecting the individual print area.
Is there a way create pdf of print areas of multiple sheets with VBA. I cannot hardcode the sheets and select them. Because the sheets to be printed change.

```vb
Sub printsheets()
   Dim rng As Range, cell As Range, sht As String, arraylist() As String, i As Integer, j As Integer
   Dim selectsheets As Sheets
   Dim fldr As FileDialog
   Dim sItem As String
   
   Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   Set rng = Range("_mapLab")
   i = 0
   j = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("_map_Lab")) - 1
   
   ReDim arraylist(j)
   With ActiveWorkbook
      For Each cell In rng
         sht = cell
         If sht = "" Then
            Exit For
         End If
         .Worksheets(sht).Activate
         .Worksheets(sht).Range(Worksheets(sht).PageSetup.PrintArea).Select
         arraylist(i) = sht
         i = i + 1
      Next cell
   End With
   
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(arraylist).Select
   With fldr
      .title = "Select a Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
      .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
      If .SHOW <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
      sItem = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
   End With
   
NextCode:
   Selection.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                 FileName:=sItem & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".pdf", _
                 Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                 IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                 OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this happening in a single workbook, the one containing this code, the range `"_map_Lab"` and all the worksheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do that on multiple sheets, using `ExportAsFixFormat`.

But you can do it (in Windows) using `PrintOut` on `"Microsoft Print to PDF"`:

```
   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ArrayList).PrintOut , , 1, , ActivePrinter:="Microsoft Print to PDF", _
    Printtofile:=False, Collate:=True, PrToFileName:=sItem & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".pdf", IgnorePrintAreas:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

### Export Print Areas to PDF

[image]

- Green - the set print areas
- Yellow - the sheets to be exported
- Red - to see if something undesired 'got through' (it didn't!)

**Main**

```vb
Sub ExportPrintAreas()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Export Print Areas"
    Const RANGE_NAME As String = "_map_Lab" ' or "_mapLab"???
    Const USE_LIST_ORDER As Boolean = True
    
    ' Define the destination folder path.
    Dim FolderPath As String:
    FolderPath = PickFolder(Application.DefaultFilePath, "Select a Folder")
    If Len(FolderPath) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Folder picker dialog canceled.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    ' Reference the range.
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = wb.Names(RANGE_NAME).RefersToRange
    ' Count the number of non-empty cells ("hmm...")...
    Dim snCount As Long: snCount = Application.CountA(rng)
    
    ' Check if any.
    If snCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No names in range.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' ... to define the array of sheet names.
    Dim SheetNames(): ReDim SheetNames(1 To snCount)
       
    ' Define new variables used in the loop.
    Dim sh As Object, cell As Range, sn As Long, SheetName As String
    
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        SheetName = CStr(cell.Value)
        If Len(SheetName) = 0 Then ' the cell is blank
            ' With the following you are enforcing the sheet names
            ' to be at the top of the range. I don't like it!
            ' You could safely remove it to allow the sheet names
            ' to be anywhere in the range.
            Exit For
        Else ' the cell is not blank
            ' Attempt to reference the sheet.
            On Error Resume Next
                Set sh = wb.Sheets(SheetName)
            On Error GoTo 0
            ' Check if a sheet was referenced.
            If Not sh Is Nothing Then ' it exists
                sn = sn + 1 ' count
                SheetNames(sn) = SheetName
                Set sh = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
            'Else ' it doesn't exist; do nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Check if no sheet was found.
    ' Thanks to 'Exit For', if the first cell was blank, it's bye bye.
    If sn = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No sheets found.", vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' The 'CountA' has counted non-empty cells but they could be located
    ' anywhere so the total count could be smaller i.e. there could be
    ' sheet names below an empty cell. Also, there could be sheet names
    ' that don't exist.
    ' Shrink the array if necessary.
    If sn < snCount Then
        ReDim Preserve SheetNames(1 To sn)
    End If
    
    ' Build the file path.
    Dim FilePath As String: FilePath = FolderPath & wb.Name & ".pdf"
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Copy the sheets to a new workbook.
    wb.Sheets(SheetNames).Copy
    ' When copying muliple sheets in one go, at least one of them
    ' needs to be visible. Sheets that are very hidden
    ' are skipped (there is no error). This code assumes that
    ' all sheets are visible.
    
    ' Reference this new workbook.
    With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        ' When copying multiple sheets in one go, they end up ordered
        ' in the order they appear in the source workbook.
        ' Reorder the sheets.
        If USE_LIST_ORDER Then
            For sn = 1 To sn
                .Sheets(SheetNames(sn)).Move After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            Next sn
        End If
        ' Export and close the new workbook.
        .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FilePath, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform. This will become useful when you set 'OpenAfterPublish' to 'False'.
    Dim Msg As Long:
    Msg = MsgBox("Sheets exported." & vbLf & vbLf _
        & "Do you want to explore the destination folder?", _
        vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, PROC_TITLE)
    ' Explore. 'vbDefaultButton2' sets the focus on the 'No' button.
    If Msg = vbYes Then
        wb.FollowHyperlink FolderPath
    End If

End Sub
```

**Help**

```vb
Function PickFolder( _
    Optional ByVal InitialFolderPath As String = "", _
    Optional ByVal DialogTitle As String = "Browse", _
    Optional ByVal DialogButtonName As String = "OK") _
As String
    With Application.FileDialog(4) ' 4 = msoFileDialogFolderPicker
        .Title = DialogTitle
        .ButtonName = DialogButtonName
        Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
        Dim FolderPath As String
        If Len(InitialFolderPath) > 0 Then
            FolderPath = InitialFolderPath
            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
            .InitialFileName = FolderPath
        End If
        If .Show Then
            FolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
            If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
            PickFolder = FolderPath
        Else
            ' Optionally, out-comment or use a message box.
            Debug.Print "'PickFolder': Dialog canceled."
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed code. This also works.